# Is it possible to provide input files list to FFmpeg in a text file instead of on command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to provide many small file inputs to ffmpeg executable on command line and I am way beyond the maximum command length for the command line. I need to provide the input list as a file. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, just pass input files to `-i` option:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c:v hevc_nvenc 1.mp4
```

concat.txt:

```
file '001.mp4'
file '003.mp4'
```

Comment: Ok but I don't want to concat the files.I would like to run a filter_complex on the inputs.

Comment: Okay, put input files in a file on Linux:
`ffmpeg -i $(cat files.txt) ...`

Comment: I can't pass the file names as parameters with the "-i" options as that causes the entire command to exceed the maximum command length supported by terminal.

Comment: Using mask is easier, this also allows framerate parameter

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's possible, but you'll probably run into other limitations doing it.

Concatenating large numbers of images can be done using FFmpeg's [pattern_type](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) "sequence" and "glob" features.  Concatenating other media can be done using [concat files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer).

However, these features clump all files into a single concatenated stream.  If you want to treat them as separate inputs in `-filter_complex`, then a different strategy is needed.  That said, it's highly unlikely that anyone would use a complex filter with so many inputs for anything other than concatenating files (like what kind of overlay or interleaving or mixing could possibly involve that many files?).

For simplicity, let's use a [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter customized for individual image files (just draw the file number on each image):

```
ffmpeg -i 0.png -i 1.png -filter_complex "[0]drawtext=text=0[i0];[1]drawtext=text=1[i1];[i0][i1]concat=2" output.mp4
```

With this format, command-line length gets to >46k at just over 1000 inputs before seeing this error message from FFmpeg:

```
1020.png: Too many open files
```

So for me, command-line length isn't the bottleneck (note that I'm on Linux).  However, if I wanted to shorten the command-line, then one easy step is to move the complex filter into a file:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.png -i 1.png -filter_complex_script script_file.txt output.mp4
```

And this reduces the same command to 11k + a script file.  If this is not enough, then the next step is to replace the input files with the [movie](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) filter ([amovie](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amovie) for audio) as exampled in the [concat documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-148).  In this case, script_file.txt looks like:

```
movie=0.png,drawtext=text=0[i0];
movie=1.png,drawtext=text=1[i1];
[i0][i1]concat=2
```

And the command is just:

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex_script script_file.txt output.mp4
```

The movie/amovie filters are not perfect replacements for inputs (I ran into this very [minor bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9787)), but are close enough for most use-cases.

In any case, this does not get around the limitation of open files, so if you exceed that limit, then you will probably have to generate video segments containing the maximum number of files, and concatenate those segments into a complete video afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg  $(ls *.mp4 |sort|xargs -i echo -i {})`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Having downloaded many .ts and .aac files I simply used cat to put all the .ts files into one large .ts file
and ditto with the .aac files
I then just used ffmpeg to combine the large .ts and .aac files

```
ffmpeg -i combined.ts -i combined.aac -c:v copy -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the command line args on each line of your text file.

`ffmpeg @/path/to/textfile.txt > output.log`

The output.log file will contain the std out. You can omit this if you just want to see the result on the screen.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on this feature? Is this a shell feature?